# Magento - Can't remove paypal as a payment method

Tags: e-commerce, magento

I'm trying to remove everything Paypal from my magento store. However, no matter what I try the Paypal payment option (on the one page checkout) refuses to leave. I've got all settings turned off/blank in admin (in default, main website and default sore view). I've even tried disabling the paypal modules completely in Config->Advanced. But no matter what I try the payment option still sticks around. All caching is off.

Anyone know what this could be?

Thanks.

Comment: Is it hard coded in the template?

Comment: No, problem persists even if I change back to the default template.

Answer (score 1):

If it is turned off in the admin and your cache is turned off, I would go in and manually remove the cache and session files from var.

root/magentoinstall/var/cache

root/magentoinstall/var/sessions

Comment: Tried doing this already, but tried again just to be sure, and no, it's still there.

Comment: Yes, I'm certain it's not a caching issue.

Comment: @edhardie   I am having same issue right now..My magento version is 1.7.0.2 .If you fixed that issue, can you please share how did you fixed that..?

Comment: @Elavarasan it's been a while since I had this happen. I'd try a) deleting everything under magentos var directory and b) [this soltuion from below](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19705564/magento-paypal-express-not-showing/19707773#19707773)

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem. Finally I got solution for this. I just posted answer for this. It may be help for you. Its working for me.

***[Click me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19705564/magento-paypal-express-not-showing/19707773#19707773)***

Answer (score 0):

Login to your admin site
Go to system ---> configuration and then at the bottom left corner, select Advanced.

The "Disable modules output" page will show up.

You can now disable the appropriate modules like Mage_Paypal and Mage_PaypalUK this will remove everything Paypal from your site. 
(Magento 1.9)

This is good if you live in some countries where Paypal does not work.