# Magento PayPal Express not showing

Tags: magento, paypal

I have a pretty standard Magento installation (Magento ver. 1.7.0.2) and I have enabled PayPal Express settings (Including API username. password & Signature all filled in). I have set the default theme to blank so that it doesn't use any of my template files but the button is not showing on any pages (product, basket or checkout - These options are set to show in the admin).

So even with the default Magento theme non of the paypal buttons show up.
Anyone seen this before? Can anyone shed any light on this?

Thanks

*edit* p.s. Mage_Paypal & Mage_PaypalUk both enabled in Advanced.

Comment: Is it visible at onepage checkout page in payment method ..?

Comment: No. Nowhere. I think it might be an issue with the Ebizmarts SagePaySuite overriding some default functionality. Will run some tests. Thanks for reply.

Comment: So i've tested with a fresh install and it's not the Sage Pay Suite giving the problem. Back to the drawing board!

Answer (score 3):

its seems like you have enabled paypal with another configuration scope ..Not in Default configuration scope or may be you have disabled paypal exp in your current configuration scope. It will override Default configuration scope even you enabled in Default configuration scope. Make sure about this..

Just go to your database. open `core_config_data`  table enable to view all datas with one page. Here you can see all your paypal configs. If you see any paypal configs with **websites** or **something** not like **default** in scope field then you have configured paypal for your current configuration scope.

**Update :**

consider your current config scope is **website**. In your `core_config_data` table set value to "**1**" for this `payment/paypal_express/active` for only the other config scopes (website) not the default. Just have a look at the following image. Then check again..It should be work now..! [image]

Comment: There were a couple of different scopes defined but they have been cleansed now and still nothing shows. Thanks.